# Is there a button for moving items up and down in a listview?

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I am coding a C# forms application where I have a ListView with multiple items.

I am wanting to move these items up and down and am wondering if there is a forms control that I can use for this, or should I get my own image, and add this to a simple button for both the up and down action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you simply create your own button with the desired image.

If you like to use the Microsoft images, you should take a look at the folder `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\VS2010ImageLibrary`. There you'll find (in another sub-folder) a `VS2010ImageLibrary.zip` file which contains lots of Microsoft images you are allowed to use within your applications. If you can't find your desired resolution you can take a look if you find a corresponding .ico file, cause these normally contains more resolutions then directly available as .png or .bmp file.

Comment: Thank you, I have VS2013, and will get the images for this version.